# How to replace the '+' prefix in customizable options value string

Tags: customizable-options, prefix

Anyone knows where this + prefix symbol in customizable options is coming from?

[image: customizable options plus symbol]

I'd like to replace it with something like "for {price}". I searched all over Magento modules and couldn't find it.

It appears in product page, cart, minicart... etc.

Any help would be much appreciated.

---

Edit:

I was on the trail of finding the source of the symbol and I came by "/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html".

Inside it was this block of code:

```
<div data-role="content" class="content">
                <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Options Details' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
                <dl class="product options list">
                    <!-- ko foreach: { data: options, as: 'option' } -->
                    <dt class="label"><!-- ko text: option.label --><!-- /ko --></dt>
                    <dd class="values">
                        <!-- ko if: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                            <span data-bind="html: $parents[1].getOptionValueUnsanitizedHtml(option.value.join('<br/>'))"></span>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                        <!-- ko if: (!Array.isArray(option.value) && ['file', 'html'].includes(option.option_type)) -->
                            <span data-bind="html: $parents[1].getOptionValueUnsanitizedHtml(option.value)"></span>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                        <!-- ko if: (!Array.isArray(option.value) && !['file', 'html'].includes(option.option_type)) -->
                        <span data-bind="text: option.value"></span>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </dd>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </dl>
            </div>
```

The title + price comes from `<span data-bind="text: option.value"></span>.`
Apparently, this is bound via knockoutJS to "/vendor/magento/module-checkout/CustomerData/DefaultItem.php" with this:

```
protected function getOptionList()
{
    return $this->configurationPool->getByProductType($this->item->getProductType())->getOptions($this->item);
}
```

No idea what this getOptions is...
Since I just wanted to get it over with already, i made a simple module with the file, did a str_replace on the return ('+' to 'only') and it worked.

Any better way to do it though?

Answer (score 1):

> **You can check in the vendor file path**

```
/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/AbstractOptions.php
```

Here **_formatPrice()** function has a **$sign='+'** variable, you can overwrite this file and change the symbol.

Comment: Hey, I've tried this, yet it still shows that pesky '+'. Could it be that it may be coming from somewhere else as well? I do have a minicart extension, but disabling it didn't remove it, so I guess it's not it.